# reporting pageloading time with php selenium

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I want to test how fast each page in my php web application loads, so i figured out i should use selenium testing. I have build this test to login on my application and visit two pages

```
<?php
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{

  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("xxxx");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/user/login");
    $this->type("id=username", "xxxx");
    $this->type("name=password", "xxxx");
    $this->click("name=submit");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->open("xxxxxx");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->open("xxxxx");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->click("link=logout");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
  }
}
?>
```

now i want to have some sort of report to output the loading time of each page this test visits. I was thinking about using php microtime but that will only output the script render time, but i want to know the full time (script render, image/css/js loading and if there are ajax calls)

Is there any possible way to access an request object to get request start and end time? or some sort of plugin to get this information?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you are using chrome inside developer tools and you can view the loading time for image,css,js files and ajax calls in the network option

Comment: That's a solution what would work but i want to have an automated way to test pages. They can differ from time to time and need to be tested  every 30 mins